# Configuring Networking for Azure function app

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I created Azure function app and Azure function, I am able to hit the Azure with default URL from internet.

I want to restrict access to my function so that it can be accessed only from the specified vnet/subnet

If I configure the Networking for the function (Function app ->network-> Access restriction ) with allow access , source setting of subscription , vnet/subnet  , I am getting 403 error (forbidden).

Please suggest the work around/correct way to configure Azure function app

Thanks
Ramabadran

Answer (score 0):

To access the Function App within the Virtual Network defined:

- Created the Function App in Consumption Plan.
- Created the Virtual Machine in the Same location of Function Ap and allowed the Ports 3389 (for Testing purpose) and HTTPS in the VM Networking.
- In Azure Portal Function App, Menu > Networking > Access Restrictions > Click on  `Add Rule`  >

**`Priority: 200`**
**`Name: AllowVNetSource`**
**`Type: Virtual Network / default subnet`**

[image]

- Go to the VM > Disable Firewall > Access the HTTP Trigger Function URL:
  [image]
- To access the function app out of the VNet, add the IP range or IP address as shown in the **Rule 100** (1st Image):

[image]

- If it is accessed out of the specified Subnet or IP Range, then it will be resulted in 403-forbidden as shown below:

[image]